# phonegap image resizer plugin to save image

Tags: android, cordova

I found a phonegap image-resizer plugin here https://github.com/raananw/PhoneGap-Image-Resizer

I tried to add it to my phonegap index on camera success to try to save image.

```
function onSuccess(imageURI) {

    window.imageResizer.storeImage(
        function(data) { 
            var image = document.getElementById('smallImage');
            image.src = imageURI; 
            alert('got img')
        }, function (error) {
            alert("Error : \r\n" + error);
            //console.log("Error : \r\n" + error);
        }, imageURI, {filename :"test",imageDataType:ImageResizer.IMAGE_DATA_TYPE_URL ,format:'jpg',directory:"/DCIM/Camera"}
    );
}
```

solved: I get error in logcat IMAGE_DATA_TYPE_URL is not defined

solved: I get a error saying null, and a black image named test.jpg is put in camera folder but is not shown in gallery (solved this by editing the imageData ImageResizer.IMAGE_DATA_TYPE_URL was not working properly still made a base64 default in the java file just edit it to url type permanently XD another was uri was having errors and subtringed the file:/// out and image was saved with no more problem)

solved: saved in same folder as gallery but it is not seen unless you rename it in the file manager (used a code snipplet)

```
    private void scanPhoto(String imageFileName)
{
  Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
  File f = new File(imageFileName);
  Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
  mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
  this.cordova.getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent); 
}
```

Problem: saved it in the same directory as the camera but when looking in gallery it shows in a group called cache, how can i make it to application name in gallery instead of cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have no need to find other image plugin for resizing. 
[option camera.getPicture](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture) in phonegap will do this for you. Change the quality,targetWidth,targetHeight to do what you want.

Comment: well what i am trying to do it both resize and save the file since the image-resizer also has a save feature

Comment: @jhdj What if we want to crop the image ?

Comment: @MuhammadRiyaz you may use canvas